# How do I change the login screen in Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome?

Tags: desktop-environments, login-screen

My question relates to the design of the login screen in Ubuntu Gnome.

I want to customise it, in that I'm not a big fan of the design.
I would like to change the slide up thing, skipping straight to the password prompt.

Preferably something that resembles macOS's login screen.

(Trying to make Ubuntu my full time environment - want to make it feel more home-y)

Thanks all

Comment: Not an answer but I never do the slide up thing, I just start typing my password.